# Manipulating a String using .substring in Java

Tags: java, string, character, substring

I'm reading line by line from a text file which contains a string followed by a white space followed by another string. It's the second string I want to use for my method.

Example of text file:

```
0h e3ne6t
ie 51b0x
6 8qlaqi
ty2 9j5dbb
nwz55 7lrwor
```

So I want 'e3ne6t', then '51b0x' etc.

I've tried using the .substring method and have tried using " " and "\s" as representations of white space.

Here's a snippet of code that should give you a good idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;
            System.out.println("lineNumber = " + lineNumber);
            int index = strLine.indexOf(" "); // tried \\s
            System.out.println("index = " + index);
            strLine.substring(index);
            System.out.println(strLine);
            if (myString.equals(strLine)) {
                System.out.println("Match Found!");;
                System.out.println("myString = " + myString );
                System.out.println("strLine =" + strLine);
            }
        }
```

I even tried changing the white space to a "+" but it still wouldn't work.

Suggestions?

Comment: A `String` in Java is *immutable*. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 3):

`substring` doesn't change the contents of the string you call it on - nothing does, as `String` is immutable in Java. Instead, it *returns* a new string which is the relevant substring. So you can use:

```
strLine = strLine.substring(index);
```

(The same is true for things like `toUpperCase`, `trim`, `replace` etc.)

Answer (score 3):

String's are **immutable** in java. you need to reassign the value retrieved by `substring` to the actual variable.

```
strLine=strLine.substring(index);
```

Also note that `indexOf(str)` doesn't take regex, so `indexOf("\\s")` would give you nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, Strings are immutable in Java.  The `substring` method returns a new `String` that is the substring.  But if you pass `index` to `substring`, then you will get a substring starting with your space character, e.g. " e3ne6t".  So I would use this:

```
strLine = strLine.substring(index + 1);
```

to get your second field, advancing past the space character, as long as `index` is not `-1` (not found).

Answer (score -1):

Manipulating a String using `.substring` in Java

[www.gleegrid.com/all_in_one/language/substring](http://www.gleegrid.com/all_in_one/language/substring)

Comment: I think you must quote the answer, since with time the link you referenced might not work